# Returning index value of element from list of integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing

New to python so will be prone to mistakes, my problem is:

A sorted array of integers was rotated an unknown number of times.

Given such an array, find the index of the element in the array in faster than linear time. If the element doesn't exist in the array, return null.

For example, given the array [13, 18, 25, 2, 8, 10] and the element 8, return 4 (the index value of 8 in the array).

You can assume all the integers in the array are unique.

The code I've already tried:

```
def find_index(x, a):
    x = input("Enter number wish to be found:  ")
    a = [13, 18, 25, 2, 8, 10]
    for element in a:
        if x not in a:
            return None
        else:
            print(a.index(x))

print(find_index())
```

I was expecting to be able to get the user to input a number, and receive back the value of the index position or `None`. I've hit a brick wall and not sure where to continue. Any ideas?

EDIT: I mixed up the error with another one. The real given error is: `find_index() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'x' and 'a'`

Comment: That code gives a different error: `TypeError: find_index() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'x' and 'a'`. Please make a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The code you provided does not produce said error.
2. Why does the function take 2 arguments, then immediately overwrite them?
3. `input` returns a string. You have to convert `x` to integer.

Anyway, the loop does not make any sense. All your function needs to do is wrap `.index`:

```
def find_index():
    try:
        x = int(input("Enter number wish to be found:  "))
    except ValueError:
        return 'You have to input an integer'
    a = [13, 18, 25, 2, 8, 10]
    try:
        return a.index(x)
    except ValueError:
        return None
```